# webpack sourcemaps missing names section

Tags: angular, webpack, source-maps, rollbar

I'm using webpack to automatically generate my sourcemaps and all seems to work find.

However the [names] section of the sourcemap seems to be missing.

Chrome doesn't have an issue with it, but Rollbar does not accept these sourcemaps for upload and gives us the:

> Error: Source map missing property 'names'

Error.

Is there a way to let webpack generate this part in the sourcemap?

I've already checked a lot of pages and found something about installing source-map-loader. But these do not reference to CSS, SASS and Typescript, which makes it seem i need css-source-map-loader and a lot more..

Comment: It seems that uglifyJs is removing this section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation it seems that the uglifyJs plugin breaks and does not uglify the code. It also removes the names section from the sourcemaps.

This only happens if you set devtool to true, if you set devtool to 'source-maps' it will work fine.